# missing value in the binary outcome when performing the propensity score matching (PSM)

Tags: missing-data, propensity-scores, matching, dependent-variable

I'm doing the propensity score matching by using R studio.
Sometimes I have missing value in the binary outcome, e.g., I wanted to see 'development of significant coronary artery disease (CAD) on coronary CT (Y or N)' after treatment A, but the patient did not get any CT scan after starting treatment A, for some (personal) reasons.

In this case, the patient seems to be excluded from the matching process.

My question is: is it just okay to exclude those patients? Because, when we have missing values in the **matching variables**, we can do the multiple imputation. Is there any similar thing for the **outcome**? That is, missing values in the matching variables -> multiple imputation, missing outcome indicator -> ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have missingness anywhere, whether in the in covariates, the treatment, or the outcome, if the asusmption of missing at random (MAR) or missing completely at random (MCAR) are met, then you can perform multiple imputation, perform that matching in each imputed dataset, estimate the effects in each imputed dataset, and then combine the estimates into a single treatment effect. You can use the `MatchThem` package to make this easier.

If whether the outcome was observed depends on unobserved factors that are related to the treatment, then the assumptions of MAR and MCAR are not satisfied. You can attempt to use a method for missing not at random (MNAR) data or accept that your estimates of the treatment effect may be slightly biased. For example, if patients who were feeling good after the treatment were less likely to get a scan (e.g., because they decided they didn't need to see the doctor anymore), then only looking at those who got the scan would make it seem like results were worse overall (because those with the best outcomes dropped out). If this missingness depends on variables that you have measured, then multiple imputation can help solve this problem, but if it depends on variables you haven't measured, then those who remain will be fundamentally different from those who didn't remain, and your treatment effect will not generalize to a meaningful population.

Comment: This is really helpful. Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks so much and another quick question. If patient X has missing value in binary outcome A (CAD/non-CAD) but not in binary outcome B (survival/death), the patient X seems to be included in the matching process for binary outcome B but is excluded in the matching process for outcome A (I use MatchIt). Then should I do some additional analysis, such as competing risk analysis because CAD and death are potentially related, at least in part?

Comment: You should ask that as a new question. I don't know about analyzing competing risk data.